# iOS/Objective-C read 4GB or greater of Zipped archive library?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, zip

I have tried using:

1. Objective-Zip
2. ZipKit

Both say they have the capability of reading 4GB or larger zipped archives.  Has anyone successfully been able to read very larged zipped content using one of the libraries mentioned above?

If you know a better zipped archive library, please let me know.

Comment: Show us the code that fails. Sounds possibly like a 32-bit data type limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and trying to solve it over couple of days.
Finally, i solved it.

With my instruction you can unzip big files (even 8GB) in iOS without any problems.

This is an step-by-step instruction how to solve it:

1) Download Objective-Zip from https://github.com/flyingdolphinstudio/Objective-Zip

2) Download MiniZip from https://github.com/nmoinvaz/minizip

3) Take 4 files - ioapi.c, ioapi.h, unzip.c, unzip.h -  from minizip folder (which you downloaded in step 2) and paste it to the Objective-Zip/MiniZip folder (override files).

4) Go to Objective-Zip/Objective-Zip/ZipFile.m and replace this string

```
int err= unzLocateFile(_unzFile, [fileNameInZip cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], 1);
```

to this

```
int err= unzLocateFile(_unzFile, [fileNameInZip cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], (unzFileNameComparer)1);
```

5) Finally, add Objective-Zip to your project and happy unzipping! :)

Now you can unzip big files in iOS. I checked on 8GB-zip, everything works like a charm!

P.S.: developer of Objective-Zip will update it with my fix as soon as possible, so this instruction is actual for Objective-Zip 0.8.1 only.

Comment: Sorry for the late response as your instructions enabled me to use Objective-Zip in my project!!  Also, Objective-Zip has incorporated the solution with modifications into the repository.  There still is an issue with Minizip to unzip Large Zip files using Mac "Compress" option. Hopefully that is resolved shortly.

Comment: Bob Z, "Large Zip" issue is unresolvable at the moment, it's an Apple problem. I created an issue on Minizip's page on GitHub, all details are here: https://github.com/nmoinvaz/minizip/issues/5

Answer (score 0):

As long the zip library supports PKWare's ZIP64 extension then it should be able to work with large files over 4GB.

1. Objective-Zip uses minizip 1.1 which supports ZIP64.
2. ZipKit website states it supports ZIP64 extension.

Both these libraries should work. I have experience with minizip 1.1 and I know for certain that it supports large files.